# How do I make shell splashes and large calibre gun fire?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I'm working on a new project about a world war two destroyer called HMCS Haida. I've been playing around with particle systems and smoke/fire domains but all of my renders come out looking unrealistic.

For example, my most recent render came out looking like this:
[image]

It's a major improvement over my previous attempts but it still looks very un realistic. For reference, I'm attempting to create an effect similar to this:
[World of Warships: Naval Legends HMCS Haida.](https://youtu.be/ZdntkBi4bRc)
Obviously I do not own this footage, all copyrights belong to Wargaming.net and I only clipped it for example purposes.

I've also been trying to create more realistic water/ocean scenes. If you have some idea of how to create that kind of water explosions (from shells landing) please share, the best I figured out is to create a smoke domain.

In my opinion the water appears too glassy. Water in the turbulent ocean shouldn't be so mirror like. Advice, criticism's and suggestions are all welcomed. I'm still rather new to Blender, but I want to make this project look as professional as possible.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I look forward to your responses!

Comment: Is this for Eevee or Cycles? How do the shaders for the fire and the water look like?

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell us what render engine you are using and show us the shaders for your fire and water. 

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this post until recently. I'm using the cycles engine. https://imgur.com/a/e0yK42e Shaders.